is it typescript bug in vue3?
vue 3.4.38
ts 5.5.4
// demo.ts
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

type Props<Comp> = Comp extends new (...arg: any[]) => { $props: infer P }
  ? P
  : unknown;

function use<T>(comp: T, defaults = () => ({}) as Props<T>) {
  return null;
}
use(
  defineComponent((p: { a: { b: 0 | 1 }; fn(): void }) => () => null),
  () => ({ a: { b: 0 /* as const */ }, fn() {} }),
  //                 ^ Uncomment it to solve.
);

run bunx tsc demo.ts, tsc error:
...\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:120196
      throw e;
      ^

Error: Debug Failure. No error for last overload signature

I find ts will work when I don't write fn function, but after I add fn, ts seems to be able to correctly identify type. but show error on tsc.
